# How to parametrize fixture from another fixture?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

Is there possibility to parametrize fixture from a fixture?

Let's say I've a fixture, which is taking *relay_number* as a parameter:

```python
@pytest.fixture
def unipi_relay(request):
    try:
        relay_number = request.param["relay_number"]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(
            "This function requires as a parameter dictionary with values for keys:"
            "\nrelay_number - passed as integer\n"
        )

    relay = RelayFactory.get_unipi_relay(relay_number)
    relay.reset()
    yield relay
    relay.reset()
```

Now I would like to have another fixture, which will yield *unipi_relay* with already passed parameter.

Reason why I want to implement such a solution is that I would like to reuse *unipi_relay* fixture a few times in single test.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: [Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not.
This is about parametrizing the fixture from a test.
What I'm looking for is parametrizing the fixture from  a fixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly what you want to achieve because you haven't put the parameters your fixture is taking. Maybe the [“factory as fixture” pattern](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#factories-as-fixtures) is what you're looking for, because you'll then be able to reuse the `unipi_relay` fixture. Please also have a look at the question [Reusing pytest fixture in the same test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826397/reusing-pytest-fixture-in-the-same-test).

Comment: Thanks, it is almost what I needed!
I can try to use that for my purpose.